# Standard Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm currently trying to solve the following problem:

> $<−, −> : C^4 × C^4 → C$
> Can we say that  $<x, y> = x_1*y_1 + x_2*y_2 + x_3*y_3 + x_4*$ say` it's an inner product?

My approach is to show that the function satisfies the following properties:

1. Linearity in the first vector:
   $ax+by=(ax_1+by_1,....,ax_n+by_n)
   <ax+by, x> = (ax_1+by_1)*z_1 + ... + (ax_n+by_n)*z_n = a<x,z> + b<y,z>$
2. Conjugate symmetry:
   $<x,y>=<y,x>
   <y,x> = y_1*x_1 + y_2*x_2 + y_3*x_3 + y_4*x_4 = x_1*y_1 + x_2*y_2 + x_3*y_3 + x_4*y_4 = <x,y>$
3. Non-negativity:
   $<x,x> = ||x_1||^2 + ||x_2||^2 + ||x_3||^2 + ||x_4||^2$
4. Non-degeneracy:
   $<x,x> \ \text{iff} \ x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=0$

This implies that $<x,y>$ is indeed an inner product. However, the answer is opposite. Could you explain me where I made a mistake, please?

Comment: Are you asking whether the map $\langle - , - \rangle : \mathbb C^4 \times \mathbb C^4 \to \mathbb C$ defined by $\langle x, y \rangle = x_1^\star y_1 + x_2^\star y_2 + x_3^\star y_3 + x_4^\star y_4$ is an inner product? (As written, I'm not 100% sure what you are asking.)

Answer (score 1):

an (Hemitian) inner product on a complex vector $V$ space must be anti-linear wrt second slot or conjugate-symmetric, that is :
$$ \forall x,y \in V, \langle x,y \rangle =\overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$$
this property ensures that $$ \forall x \in V, \langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}
$$
which makes positivity of $\langle x,x \rangle$ meaninfull.
if you take $x=y=(i,0,0,0)$, you get:$\langle x,x \rangle <0$, which contradicts the axiom of positivity, so the given bilinear function is not an inner product.